# Trunking between two Cisco 3750s to another desktop switch

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan

So I'm trying to scrape all the memory I have from college where we used Cisco almost a decade ago, but I haven't touched them since then. I'm trying to clean up our internal network a little bit because we currently have 4 little 5-8 port switches sitting on a shelf connected to our firewall, but we had 2 Cisco 3750s in the basement.  I've been looking through manuals and forums online as well as several different posts here, but I'm still having some problems.

I have three Vlans (10, 20, and 30) on the first of the two switches that are going to various different management devices.  I have a Trunk port setup between the two allowing all Vlans currently.  On the second switch I currently only have one Vlan setup for our internal LAN. One of the ports on the second switch is going to go to a building next door that we have some offices in, but rather than drag 8 CAT5e and taking up 8 ports on the switch, I'm just going to drag 1 and have a small desktop switch.  It's just two desks with a couple computers and printers.  I want THIS port to also be able to get into the management devices on the first switch with Vlans 10, 20, and 30. I set it to a trunk port that allows all four Vlans, but I don't have any access until I set the Native Vlan, which obviously only works for one of the four.  I'm sure it's possible, but I'm not sure which part of the configuration I'm missing.  Maybe I'm going down an entirely wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: Most little switches like that are unmanaged and do not support VLANs.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yeah, I'm talking about on the Cisco 3750.  The VLANs are arbitrarily assigned just for network separation.  Nothing outside of these 2 switches is actually using the VLANs

Answer (score 0):

I would see another solution to your problem than trunking to a non managed switch that would not allow it.

I have more a router background than an expert on switch, as such if your switch in the remote office does not support VLAN I suggest to you to make sure the gateway used by those computers is routed correctly to be able to talk to those VLAN.

You could route via the switch or from your router directly. For that part I dont know your setup, but if all the VLAN (0, 10,20, 30) is routed correctly inside the router it's easy to make allow rule to allow the routing between VLAN.